# javascript function not taking form value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create a really simple radio button quiz with javascript and an html form. When I try to take the form question values and put them into variables, they're not being taken. When I console.log q1 I just get undefined.

I've tried giving the radio buttons id's with getElementById, doesn't work. I've also tried document.forms['infoForm']['question1'].value;

```js
function results() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var q1 = document.getElementsByName('question1').value;
  var q2 = document.getElementsByName('question2').value;
  var q3 = document.getElementsByName('question3').value;
  var q4 = document.getElementsByName('question4').value;

  console.log(q1);
}
```

```html
<form name="infoForm" id="infoForm" onsubmit="return results();" method="post">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Here's a Quiz!</legend>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="R1">R<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="W">W<br>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 2<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="R2">R<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="W">W<br>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 3<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="R3">R<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="W">W<br>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 4<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="R4">R<br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

When using console.log() for the question variables I would like to see the value the user has actually chosen, instead of undefined.

Comment: `q1` doesn't have a `value` property. Neither do any of the other collections.

Comment: `getElements` returns, well, *elements*, not a single *element* ... `getElementById` would be the better choice and should work as expected, could you show us that try?

Comment: @olian04 although that is slightly related to the question and is probably the next problem the OP is facing, that does not answer the question he asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getElementsByName()` returns an array of elements. However, using it, and grabbing the first item, will only give you the first item in the in the radio button set, and not the selected radio button.

Since you have `name` attributes, you can just use the path to get the element like this:

```
document.infoForm.question1.value
```

You can then do that for all 4 questions so it looks something like this:

```js
function results() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var q1 = document.infoForm.question1.value;
  var q2 = document.infoForm.question2.value;
  var q3 = document.infoForm.question3.value;
  var q4 = document.infoForm.question4.value;

  console.log(q1, q2, q3, q4);
}
```

```html
<form name="infoForm" id="infoForm" onsubmit="return results();" method="post">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Here's a Quiz!</legend>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="R1">R<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="W">W<br>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 2<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="R2">R<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="W">W<br>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 3<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="R3">R<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="W">W<br>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      quiz question 4<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="W">W<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="R4">R<br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

There are some errors in your code.

The function `getElementsByName()` returns a `NodeList`, so you can't access the property `value` on it. Try to get the first index of it: `getElementsByName()[0].value`

The variable event is not defined. I guess that you're using the function `results` as an event listener. If so, the event is sent as a parameter and you need to define it:

```
function results(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var q1 = document.getElementsByName('question1')[0].value;
  var q2 = document.getElementsByName('question2')[0].value;
  var q3 = document.getElementsByName('question3')[0].value;
  var q4 = document.getElementsByName('question4')[0].value;

  console.log(q1);
}
```

Comment: That will return the first item in the radio list always, and not the selected one.

Comment: That's right! Sorry, I didn't realize that. Thanks for the comment